# stagnant water in my tumble or 1 gallon container, how many days until it becomes contaminated or undrinkable?

Tags: food-safety

How many days, or even weeks until a certain water inside the container (a tumbler, or maybe a 1 gallon water container) becomes undrinkable?

Does it vary on container? If so, I am using a plastic 1 gallon container usually found in water dispenser and my thermal tumbler.

Note that the water is in drinkable state before putting it in a clean container, I've asked this question because after a month of not using the water inside the dispenser I noticed that there are some tiny black particles at the bottom of the gallon container, I'm thinking that it might be contaminated.

*The dispenser is just a normal dispenser without any kind of filter

The water dispenser looks like this

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the water, and how clean is the container?

Comment: A water is in drinkable state before putting it in a clean container, I've asked this question because after a month of not using the water inside the dispenser I noticed that there are some tiny black particles at the bottom of the gallon container, I'm thinking that it might be contaminated.

Comment: Water has a pretty long shelf life.  It become contaminated when it is contaminated.

Comment: Is it an open or sealed container?  Sealed containers can have a long life (especially when treated), but open containers the water gets ... stale, for a lack of a better word.  Treatments also matter, as some will kill or remove microorganisms but not provide long lasting protection (eg, ozone treatment, reverse osmosis)

Comment: Does the container involve a carbon filter (one very common source of "black particles"); is it open to the air to be used as an insect breeding site (another source...); or to collect dust (a third source?)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any official guideline on storing drinking water, probably because people just don't do it usually. But for other purposes of water storage (humidifiers etc.) the rule of thumb is that water which will sit around for more than a week has to be treated.

If anything, the rules for drinking water should be shorter (because you can have amoebas and other stuff, not just the legionellas risk from humidifiers) and not longer. So a week would be the upper limit, but shorter is better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it dependence from various others factors.

- For example water the chlorination of water. How much chorion are in.
- Then from the area that is bottled. What kind of microorganism are in
  the air and or the bottle.
- From the time of the year. Winter or summer. Summer is hotter so more and faster growing microorganism.
- From the type of the bottle. If it dark or transparent.
- From    where it would be stored. It would be sunny? The average temperature?
- And last how much air you would trap inside the bottle.

As you can understand there are so many factors so you can't have a specific
   number.

Comment: Food safety does not try to predict when food will spoil. It just tells you a specific (conservative) number before which it cannot have spoiled, worst case assumed.